# Separate odd and even numbers into different output files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to separate odd and even numbers from one input file and the output is into two different files (one for odd numbers and the other for even numbers).

I have never done anything like that. How would I go about this? Would it have to run twice to have different output files?

Comment: What, if anything, have you done so far? Do you know how to get the data from the input file? How to process it? How to determine which values in the input are odd and even? How to export the result to an output file?

Comment: Down voting because you've made minimal effort both with your question and with finding a solution, or showing a willingness to try and learn from the ample resources that already exist

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I know the basic I/O. I have looked at the other examples, and I know how to seperate odds and even into list but all the other examples people talk about how they have to run the script twice. I was getting an error on how the file didnt meet the the requirements I think since the odd one was first it wouldnt go into the even output. Sorry for my horible English.

Comment: @Matt Coubrough, Okay, thank you I like yout swag on how you think I havent been working on learning how to do this for over a week but you just know everything. My English sucks I was just trying to be as clear as posible.

Comment: @Guywith6Magikarps. if you struggle with English, remember code is less ambiguous: **include yours**, and the full error traceback. This would show that you have put some effort in so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could do it:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt("test.txt")

odd = []
even = []

for ele in a:
    if ele % 2 == 0:
        even.append(ele)
    else:
        odd.append(ele)
```

First you read a file using `a = np.loadtxt("test.txt")`, then you sort the contents into two arrays `even` and `odd` and finaly you save the files using `np.savetxt("odd.txt", odd)` and `np.savetxt("even.txt", even)`

**Edit:** As suggested by jonrsharpe you could do it more efficiently as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt("test.txt")

np.savetxt("odd.txt", a[a%2==1])
np.savetxt("even.txt", a[a%2==0])
```

Comment: As you're using `numpy`, you could be more efficient with e.g. `np.savetxt("odd.txt", a[a%2==1])`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You are absolutly right. However, I thought this way is the easiest to understand. The way the question is formulated I thought this could be of advantage. However, if you think the other way should be used, then I can edit the answer acordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I'm just trying to learn on my own and I had no idea how to work this one out. =)